# How to select and remove an atomic block

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a an atomic block which displays an image. I want to add a 'click-to-delete' button in the top corner of the image.

It seems like using `Modifier.removeRange` would work but how do I get the selection state of the atomic block?

Or is there an easier way? like `removeBlockWithKey(key)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a [custom](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#content) atomic block. then you can get the block key with `this.props.block.getKey()`. then create the `SelectionState` with the key like

```
SelectionState.createEmpty(key).merge({focusOffset:this.props.block.getText().length})
```

Comment: how do you get this.props.block.getText() , where can i get the block variable  and props

Comment: find block in editorcontent